# Python/Visual Studio error : The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable does not exist

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just reinstalled windows so I had to reinstall VS code and Python but I can't even run a "hello world" without getting this error:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Python37" does not exist.
```

The interpreter used is my Python installation.

This is what I have in my path:

```
C:\Program Files\Python37;C:\Program Files\Python37\dlls;C:\Program Files\Python37\lib
```

[image]

I tried adding this `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe;` to the beginning of the path but it didn't solve the issue.

What should I do to get rid of that message and start coding again? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's value do you set of "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" configuration in the User settings.json file? The error message shows you set the value of 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Python37'.

Open the Command Palette(Ctrl+Shift+P), type in 'Terminal: Select Default Shell' and select a shell. Or on the Terminal panel select the drop-down list of the shell and click 'Select Default Shell'.